# iPhone 6 email display at half width

Tags: ios, iphone, email

For some reason one of our email test user is seeing the email being displayed at half width on her iPhone 6.

Same issue as on the apple website's discussion:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6324196

Can anyone advise what to do? Is this a problem of the new IOS or could it be something wrong with our email template?

Thanks!

Comment: I would say something wrong with your template.
I haven't seen anything like that in my emails.

Are you able to post your code so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: But just found out it's user specific. Only that user has that problem (only with that email though). Other people who have iPhone 6 don't have issue with that email as the template seemed to be rendering perfectly on their iPhone 6. Also, it's rendering perfectly on Litmus as well. Still something wrong with the email template?

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. Probably not then. 
Seems more likely to be the settings in that persons app. I know gmail on Android there is an option in settings that can affect the way emails render, I don't have experience with apps on iOS devices, so I can't confirm for sure.

Comment: Yeah it's truly a puzzle. If anybody has any insight or even how to fix her setting would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but googling for an answer for this problem, I found a solution that worked for me.

Just adding `<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />` in the `<head>` of your email should do the trick.

References: [Litmus](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6871-ios-11-rendering-my-email-1-2-the-width-of-the-screen) | [Hteumeuleu](https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-apple-mail-in-ios-10-c7031f6d704d)